# How to change Android Studio to attach debugger to a port other than 8600

Tags: android, ddms, android-studio-2.3, usb-debugging

My Version is Android Studio 2.3.2

The problem I am facing is, I have a service which is listening on port 8600 and I cannot change this service to use a different port. Its a microstructure atchitecture and I have about 40 odd services with webconfig setting the service to listen to 8600.

Now when I try to debug a Android App, Android Studio tries to attach the debugger to port 8600 and fails (as expected since its in use by other process).

[image]

I then opened the Android Device Monitor (Tools>Android>Android Device Monitor),
opened Preferences & in the DDMS section changed the port to a different one[image]

The devices lists the device & process with the new port now, however when I try to attach the debugger now, it still gives me the same old message that it cannot attach to 8600.
[image]

I am a little new(er) to Android Studio/Android Development.
All the help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the changes are saved, and restart android studio.

Comment: Yes they were saved. I can tell by restarting Android Studio and going back to DDMS seciton on Android Device Monitor. It showed the new port. Still Android Studio keeps trying to attach debugger to 8600 (its frustrating).